# Mixing dependent types and 'concrete' types in Scala 3

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm fairly new to Scala in general, and Scala 3 in particular, and I'm trying to write some code that deals with transparently encoding + decoding values before they are passed to another library.

Basically, I need to map a set of types like `Int`s to a counterpart in the underlying library. The code I've written is too verbose to replicate here in full, but here's a minimal example demonstrating the kind of thing, using a higher-kinded `Encoder` type that encapsulates encoding values into types which depend on the values' original types:

```scala
trait Encoder[T] {
    type U
    def encode(v: T): U
}

object Encoder {
    given Encoder[Int] with {
        override type U = String

        override def encode(v: Int): String = v.toString
    }
}

case class Value[T : Encoder](v: T) {
    val encoder: Encoder[T] = summon[Encoder[T]]
}
```

I also need to be able to write functions that deal with specific types of `Value` and which have 'concrete' return types. Like this:

```scala
def doStuff(v1: Value[Int]): String = {
    v1.encoder.encode(v1.v)
}
```

However, even though in this case `v1.codec.encode` does indeed return a `String`, I get an error:

```
-- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: -------------------------------------------------
2 |    v1.encoder.encode(v1.v)
  |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |    Found:    v1.encoder.U
  |    Required: String
```

What can I do differently to solve this error? Really appreciate any pointers to help a newbie out

Comment: How do you even know the return will be `String`? BTW, the whole design feels awkward.

Comment: Because `Encoder[Int].U` is `String`.

Comment: You are assuming that will be the only one, which the compiler will not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am assuming what will be the only one, sorry?

Comment: You are either assuming that there will be only one `Encoder[Int]` or that all `Encoder[Int]` will have `String` as `U` Both are false and thus the compiler will not assume that.

Comment: The type of `encoder` is `Encoder[Int]`. Full stop. Which subclasses of `Encoder` exist *currently* is irrelevant (and `given`s are just subclasses by another name), the compiler isn't going to go looking for them. All it knows is that `Encoder[int]` has a field called `U` whose type is "literally anything". We can't infer anything about it.

Comment: Aha, of course, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for helping me see that! Is there any sensible way I tell the compiler that I’m only interested in `Value`s with `Encoder`s that encode to `String`?

Comment: What about something like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ssfn2v0LScqQOQHU3kiarg/8 ?

Answer (score 3):

Answering the question in the comments

> Is there any sensible way I tell the compiler that I’m only interested in `Value`s with `Encoder`s that encode to `String`?

You can force `Value` to remember its encoder's result type with an extra type argument.

```
case class Value[T, R](val v: T)(
  using val encoder: Encoder[T],
        val eqv: encoder.U =:= R,
)
```

The `encoder` is the same as your `encoder`, just moved to the `using` list so we can use it in implicit resolution.

`eqv` is a proof that `R` (our type parameter) is equivalent to the encoder's `U` type.

Then `doStuff` can take a `Value[Int, String]`

```
def doStuff(v1: Value[Int, String]): String = {
    v1.eqv(v1.encoder.encode(v1.v))
}
```

Let's be clear about what's happening here. `v1.encoder.encode(v1.v)` returns an `encoder.U`. Scala isn't smart enough to know what that is. However, we *also* have a proof that `encoder.U` is equal to `String`, and that proof can be used to convert an `encoder.U` to a `String`. And that's exactly what [`=:=.apply`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/3.0.2/scala/=:=.html#apply-d26) does.

We have to do this back in the `case class` because you've already lost the type information by the time we hit `doStuff`. Only the `case class` (which instantiates the implicit encoder) knows what the result type is, so we need to expose it there.

If you have other places in your codebase where you don't care about the result type, you can fill in a type parameter `R` for it, or use a wildcard `Value[Int, ?]`.

Comment: Another option would be to make `R` a type member and use an `Aux` type to get the refinement.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest giving [Match Types](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/match-types.html) a try if we are only talking about Scala 3 here.

```scala
import scala.util.Try

type Encoder[T] = T match
  case Int => String
  case String => Either[Throwable, Int]

case class Value[T](v: T):
  def encode: Encoder[T] = v match
    case u: Int => u.toString
    case u: String => Try(u.toInt).toEither


object Main extends App:
  val (v1, v2) = (Value(1), Value(2))
  def doStuff(v: Value[Int]): String =
    v.encode

  println(doStuff(v1) + doStuff(v2)) //12
  println(Value(v1.encode).encode) //Right(1)
```